# Create shared variables between p-threads without creating shared memory

Tags: c, multithreading, variables, pthreads, shared

Is there a way to create shared variables between p-threads without creating shared memory?
Can a parent procedure declare variables, which would be also altered by the child-threads created (fork)?
Can volatile or extern help?

I want to avoid creating shared memory for all the threads..

Comment: Yes, it's really easy.  They are already shared, (which is somewhat the point - inter-thread comms is easier).

Comment: Threads? Fork? Shared memory? This sounds a bit confused...

Comment: The point of pthreads is that the threads runs within the same address space, so they share all memory. fork() is not pthreads though.